# Linq query averages

Tags: linq

I can run this in Linqpad and it works fine but in VS when i run it the result throws errors because of the Avg, Max and Min statements.  Can anyone advise how i need to change this to get the desired result?

```
            tickets = from t in dbContext.TblOmTasks
                      join o in dbContext.TblOms on t.OMID equals o.OMID
                      join ls in dbContext.LkpStatusBasics on t.OMTaskStatus equals ls.ID
                      where t.OMID == SiteId
                      where ls.Status.Contains(status)

                      group t by new { Y = t.Created.Value.Date.Year, M = t.Created.Value.Date.Month } into grp
                      orderby grp.Key.M
                      select new TBS
                      {
                          Month = new DateTime(grp.Key.Y, grp.Key.M, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                      ,Avg = grp.Average(g => Convert.ToInt32((g.Updated.HasValue ? g.Updated - g.Created : DateTime.Now - g.Created).Value.Days))
                      ,Max = grp.Max(g => Convert.ToInt32((g.Updated.HasValue ? g.Updated - g.Created : DateTime.Now - g.Created).Value.Days))
                      ,Min = grp.Min(g => Convert.ToInt32((g.Updated.HasValue ? g.Updated - g.Created : DateTime.Now - g.Created).Value.Days))

                      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EF Core still can not translate Timestamp.Days. So use appropriate functions.

```cs
tickets = 
   from t in dbContext.TblOmTasks
   join o in dbContext.TblOms on t.OMID equals o.OMID
   join ls in dbContext.LkpStatusBasics on t.OMTaskStatus equals ls.ID
   where t.OMID == SiteId
   where ls.Status.Contains(status)
   group t by new { Y = t.Created.Value.Date.Year, M = t.Created.Value.Date.Month } into grp
   orderby grp.Key.M
   select new TBS
   {
        Month = new DateTime(grp.Key.Y, grp.Key.M, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Avg = grp.Average(g => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(g.Created, g.Updated ?? DateTime.Now),
        Max = grp.Max(g => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(g.Created, g.Updated ?? DateTime.Now),
        Min = grp.Min(g => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(g.Created, g.Updated ?? DateTime.Now)
   };
```

Comment: as we say, 'yah beauty', that sorted the situation. Many thanks